# Creating a portable app: is there a list of shared libraries available in any linux distro?

Tags: linux, docker

I am trying to create a compiled Linux application that can run on as many Linux desktop distro's as possible (without recompilation). I am assuming x86_64 architecture; I understand that compiled code is in general not portable between different architectures. I would like this application to work without external dependencies,  except for dependencies that are available on any reasonable Linux desktop distro.

The idea is to compile this application in a Docker image,  e.g. based on quay.io/pypa/manylinux_2_28_x86_64:2024-02-04-ea37246, and then copy it to another distro, possibly together with some of the shared libraries it depends on.

I have already learned that it is a bad idea to copy libc.so from the Docker image to another distro; libc.so is tightly linked to the kernel, and will usually not work on a different Linux version. That is not a big problem: libc.so is available in any reasonable Linux installation. My docker image has libc version 2.28, so my application could work on any distro with libc version 6 or greater.

There are more shared libraries that don't seem to be portable;  I have experimentally identified a few of them,  like libdl.so. I assume that libdl.so is also available in any reasonable desktop distro.

Some others sort of work, with issues: e.g. libfontconfig.so.1 copied from my Docker image to on Fedora 29 works with a warning `unknown element "reset-dirs"`

Here is a list of shared libraries from my docker that will not work on Fedora 29. It is most probably not complete,  and I am not confident that they are all available on other distro's.

- libc
- libdl
- librt
- libpthread
- libstdc++
- libnssckbi
- libglib-2

I'd very much like to use a more systematic approach than experimenting with different distro's. Hence my question: is there a list of shared libraries that I can assume to be available on any reasonable distro, say with libc >= 2.28? Or maybe some "minimal" distro, so that I can assume that an application that works on that distro will work on others as well?

Comment: Are you building a standalone binary (that you could statically compile), or a Python wheel package, or something else?  Especially in a Docker context, how important is running on Alpine Linux, which doesn't use GNU libc?

Comment: I am building a standalone binary (starting from python + pyqt6 and using cxfreeze for compilation). I wasn't aware of Alpine Linux not using GNU libc. Being able to handle that would be ideal, but I guess that is not trivial.